# What does "broken pipe" mean?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, latex, pipe, texlive

I was trying to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 and got a funny message. I am currently stuck between versions, can't go forward or back. All I have are terminal command functions, no GUI.
These are my results (typed longhand) after running:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
87 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 7 to remove, and 1732 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed
need to get 0B/404 MB of archives
After this operation, 257 MB of additional disk space will be used
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages...
(Reading database... 423378 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack... /texlive-latex-base-doc_2015.20160320-1_all.deb
unpacking texlive-latex-base-doc (2015.20160320-1) over (2013.20140215-1)...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-latex-base-doc_2015.20160320-1_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to Trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/url/url.tx.gz, which is also in package texlive-latex-recommended-doc 2013.20140215-1
dpkg-deb: error subprocess paste was killed by signal (broken pipe)
Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: for now these files have been included
Warning: but expect inconsistencies
Warning: these packages should be rebuilt with tex-common
Warning: please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/00updmap.cfg
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/101modern.cfg
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10texlive-base.cfg
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/texlive-latex-base.cfg
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/texlive-latex-extra.cfg
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/texlive-pictures.cfg
Errors were encountered while processing /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-latex-base-doc_2015.20160320-1_all.deb
E: Subprocess /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The literal meaning of broken pipe is that a pipe is a way for more than one process to communicate with each other and a broken pipe is when one of the processes tries to write or read from the pipe only to discover the pipe is closed (for example, because the other process closed). While this doesn't solve your problem it does try to explain a pipe.

Comment: The important part of the error is the two lines above - the 'trying to overwrite' part. Only one package can provide any file. When two packages try to provide the same file, they *conflict*. Conflicting packages cannot both be installed at the same time. Remove one, your choice which one.

Answer (score 2):

This will make you get rid off the apt-get error

```
sudo dpkg --force-all --purge texlive-latex-base-doc
```

Comment: Dear muru  & m0ar'nd'm0re ...thank you, that was a life-saver. Finally got 16.04 to install. I still have some issues with it but at least my files were saved and am online again, which is leagues ahead from where I was.